# Is Polymorphism possible in C?

Tags: c

Can I include or declare a function inside a structure? I am trying to achieve polymorphism in C. If defining a function isn't the correct way to do it, what other methods can I use?

Comment: You can't have `struct`s inherit from other `struct`s, so subclass-polymorphism isn't possible in vanilla C (without doing it yourself).

Comment: @voithos Actually that is possible in plain C.

Comment: Polymorphism in C: just using function pointer and casting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Polymorphism as a feature of object-oriented languages is not available in C. Neither are encapsulation and inheritance - the language does not have the corresponding features.

This does not mean, however, that it is impossible to model the corresponding behavior with the regular features of C: it is possible to build a library that lets you produce behavior that looks like polymorphism, for example, by using arrays of function pointers.